# ec2 putty connect problem

Tags: amazon-ec2, putty

I have followed Amazon instructions to the letter and it does not work.

ec2-api-tools-1.3-34128 - this is the api tools that I got from Amazon 
Set it up following instructions. Checked everything to make sure I follow instructions. When I try to use it, I only get: "invalid.blabla" depending on what command do I try to use. 
Anybody with this problem?

I deleted all my instances and all key pairs. 
Created new ones (instance and key pair). 
Setup putty all over again like instructions say I should do 
(creating .ppk file and everything). 
Still the problem remains. 
When I try to connect to my ec2 instance using putty 
I get "login as : " ????????

Also, I am using windows vista. 
Is this a problem.

Thanks

Comment: No one got an "invalid blabla" error. Be more specific about it. It may mean nothing to you, but it is needed for someone to answer. Also, try to log in as root. That is, type root in putty's log in screen.

Comment: +1 for `No one got an "invalid blabla" error`

Answer (score 11):

Had this same problem.  I found that in putty I had to do three things (only 2 of which are mentioned in the amazon guide at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/gsg/2007-01-19/putty.html)

1. provide the converted private key in the ssh -> Auth section
2. provide the dns name or IP
3. go to Connection -> Data and enter "ec2-user" as the Auto-login username

Hope this saves someone else 20 mins!

Comment: Thanks! They changed it to ec2-user, but all the docs still say root!

Comment: ubuntu works now, 5 years later.  I actually did not see that mentioned in the docs.

Comment: for me, i input ubuntu as username

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure that you put "root" as the auto-login account in the "Data" section?

Comment: didnt work for my ubuntu instance.  refused to log in as "root".

Answer (score 2):

A mistake I made than gave me the same error message was setting 
"**root**@ec2-.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" as the value in the "Host Name (or IP Address)" field in putty.

You need to specify "**ubuntu**@ec2-.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com".